# Suppose 11.05.2015 is the date provided by user then system should display output as weekday is monday

Tags: python, date, dayofweek

## I tried these variations, but didn't succeed:

```
print calendar.monthcalendar(z,y)

print datetime.date(y,x,z).weekday()

print datetime.date(y,x,z).strftime('%A')
```

Comment: What is your error?  Did you import `datetime` first?

Comment: Yes, I have import datetime and the error that I am getting is
    print datetime.date(y,x,z).weekday()
ValueError: day is out of range for month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a time object from the `time` module and then grab the weekday from `calendar`:

```
calendar.day_name[time.strptime('11.05.2015', '%d.%m.%Y').tm_wday]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert user input (`s` in the example below) to a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) object. Then you can utilize [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to print the day of the week:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = "11.05.2015"
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d.%m.%Y")
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 11, 0, 0)
>>> d.strftime("%A")
'Monday'
```